# Hover effect not working only in iPhone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have an unusual problem. It works in Android phones but it won't work on an iPhone. I tested it on iPhone 4 and iPhone 6s.

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0fugn1uv/)

**CSS:**

```
.address {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Only the -webkit- prefix is required these days */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}
.address h1{
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #00426e;
}

.address::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.address:hover::before {
    background: transparent;
}

.address__media {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.address__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #00426e;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.address:hover .address__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

.address__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -webkit-calc(-100% - 10px) );
            transform: translateY( calc(-100% - 10px) );

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.address:hover .address__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<article class="address">
    <img class="address__media" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/f0a95617f8.png">
    <div class="address__overlay">
         <h1 class="address__overlay__title">London</h1>
         <p class="address__overlay__content">
            This is a test address<br />
            Okay, it's an awesome address<br />
            Cool Bro
         </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

What do you think could be the problem?! Is there an iPhone specific css that needs to be added?

Answer (score 0):

Comment out or remove `position: absolute` from `.address::before` and it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/0fugn1uv/10/

And also, some of your transitions need -webkit- before that. It still works without it. But its safe to put it in there.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I notice that it doesn't work when I click on the name, "London". It works only when I click on the blank space above the name in an iphone. Any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hover option in devices will work like onclick in touch devices.

In your case `position:absolute` from `.address::before` is above all other div so basically when you touch the "london" text your are touching `.address::before` not the `.address`, so the hover styles not applied.

Since `z-index` is not properly specified the default value might applied and thats the reason it works on other devices.

Either you can remove the "absolute" value or assign lesser value of z-index.

```
.address::before{
 content: ' ';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 z-index:-1;/*added code*/
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: transparent;
 transition: background .35s ease-out;
}
```

Update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fugn1uv/14/) with lesser value of z-index.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. It doesn't work when I click on "London". It works only when I click on the space above London. Any work around for this?